# Beginner at C, float variables outputting as "0.00" after arithmetic.

Tags: c

I am new to C and I am having trouble with a basic program that converts dollars to euros. When I print the final output both the dollar and euro amount is "0.00".
Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()

{
    float usd = 0.00;
    float euro = 0.00;
    const float conversion = 0.75;

    printf("Please enter the amount of USD you want to convert to Euros: ");
    scanf("%f", &usd);

    euro = (usd * conversion);
    printf("\n%.2f USD equals %.2f Euros.", &usd, &euro);


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see this is answered, but you can prevent this happening in future by enabling warnings for your compiler. If you're using gcc, add "-Wall" to enable all warnings. It'll tell you when you're using the wrong type in printf and scanf fields. Visual Studio and the others will have an equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `printf` line to this:

```
printf("\n%.2f USD equals %.2f Euros.", usd, euro);
```

You are passing the addresses of `usd` and `euro` rather than the values themselves.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("\n%.2f USD equals %.2f Euros.", usd, euro);
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't want to put '&' in front of your variable names in your `printf()` function. This will return the memory address of the variable, and not the value stored in the variable. Try removing them and see if you get the output you are looking for.

Comment: that's only true for the printf call, he still needs the & in the scanf.